# Is it wrong to pass an object to the @DELETE API path?

Tags: java, api, rest, http-delete

I am creating a REST API using Java. Is it wrong if I pass an object to the `@DELETE` path? In the case below, I have passed an 'User' object rather than passing an UserID. Is it wrong?

```
@DELETE
@Path("delete_user")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String deleteUser(User user) {
    System.out.println("Called delete");
    DatabaseDriver db = new DatabaseDriver();
    Boolean status = db.deleteUser(user);
    if (status) {
        System.out.println("Deleted " + user.getUsername());
        return "True";
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Couldn't delete " + user.getUsername());
        return "False";
    }
}
```

Comment: does it work? does it do what you want it to do?

Comment: you'd better not. ```Delete``` is similar to ```Get```, you should use post if you want to pass a pojo, or just pass an identified field of ```User``` via code like ```delete_user?uid=123``` or use ```@PathVariable``` with ```delete_user/{uid}```. Your code will make everything of ```user``` null